# How to count occurence of IDs and show this amount with name of item with this ID from other table in SQL?

Tags: sql

if I have tables

Person: ID_Person, Name

Profession: ID_Prof, Prof_Name, ID_Person

If ID_Person appears multiple times in second table and I want to show all Person names with number of their professions how can I do this?

I know that if I want to count something I can write
SELECT ID_Person, count(*) as c
FROM Profession
GROUP BY ID_Person;
but don't know how to link it with column from other table in order to proper values.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `JOIN`. In this case, you would join `Person` and `Profession` on the `ID_Person` column.

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag the DBMS (SQL Server, PostegreSQL, MySQL, Oracle ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way (MySQL InnoDB)

```
Person
+-----------+-------+
| ID_Person | Name  |
+-----------+-------+
|         1 | bob   |
|         2 | alice |
+-----------+-------+

Profession
+---------+--------------------+-----------+
| ID_Prof | Prof_Name          | ID_Person |
+---------+--------------------+-----------+
|       1 | janitor            |         1 |
|       2 | cook               |         1 |
|       3 | computer scientist |         2 |
|       4 | home maker         |         2 |
|       7 | astronaut          |         2 |
+---------+--------------------+-----------+


select Name, count(Prof_Name) 
from Person left join Profession 
on (Person.ID_Person=Profession.ID_Person) 
group by Name;

+-------+------------------+
| Name  | count(Prof_Name) |
+-------+------------------+
| alice |                3 |
| bob   |                2 |
+-------+------------------+
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To just show those with multiple `Profession` then you would `join` the two tables, and aggregate with `count()` using `group by` and filter using `having()`:

```
select pe.ID_Person, pe.Name, count(*) as ProfessionCount
from Person pe
  inner join Profession pr
    on pe.ID_Person = pr.ID_Person
group by pe.ID_Person, pe.Name
having count(*)>1
```

If you want to show the professions for those people as well:

```
select 
    multi.ID_Person
  , multi.Name
  , multi.ProfessionCount
  , prof.ID_Prof
  , prof.Prof_Name
from (
    select pe.ID_Person, pe.Name, count(*) as ProfessionCount
    from Person pe
      inner join Profession pr
        on pe.ID_Person = pr.ID_Person
    group by pe.ID_Person, pe.Name
    having count(*)>1
  ) multi
  inner join Profession prof
    on multi.ID_Person = prof.ID_Person
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this I believe. The left join will bring in all the data and won't exclude any users.
The join can also be a inner join. Inner join would then only show users that exist in both tables.

**LEFT**

```
select x.ID_Person, count(x.ID_Person) as [count] from table1  x
left join table2 y on y.ID_Person= x.ID_Person
where x.ID_Person <> null
group by x.ID_Person
```

**INNER**

```
select x.ID_Person, count(y.ID_Person) from table1 x
inner join table2 y on y.ID_Person= x.ID_Person
group by x.ID_Person
```

Answer (score 0):

you can probably try something like this below. However, you will have to think about whether or not you need to left join versus inner join. You would want to left join if there is potentially someone who has not had any professions and therefore does not exist in the professions table.

```
SELECT  pe.Name 
      , Professions = COUNT(pr.Prof_Name)

FROM    dbo.Person      (NOLOCK)     pe 
JOIN    dbo.Profession  (NOLOCK)     pr ON pe.ID_Person = pr.ID_Person

GROUP BY pe.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably counting in  a subquery:

```
select
  id_person,
  name,
  (select count(*) from profession pr where pr.id_person = p.id_person) as profession_count
from person p;
```

You can achieve the same with an outer join:

```
select
  p.id_person,
  p.name,
  coalesce(pr.cnt, 0) as profession_count
from person p
left join (select id_person, count(*) as cnt from profession group by id_person) pr
  on pr.id_person = p.id_person;
```

It's usually a good idea to aggregate before joining. Anyway, this is how to join first and aggregate then:

```
select
  p.id_person,
  p.name,
  coalesce(count(pr.id_person), 0) as profession_count
from person p
left join profession pr on pr.id_person = p.id_person
group by p.id_person, p.name;
```

As per standard SQL it would suffice to group by p.id_person, as the name functionally depends on the id (i.e. the id uniquely defines a person, so it's one single name belonging to it). Some DBMS however don't fully comply with the standard here and demand you to either put the name in the group by clause as shown or dummy-aggregate it in the select clause (e.g. `max(p.name)`) instead.